# Assigning string literal to char*: const_cast<char *> vs using char array

Tags: c++, string, casting

I'm using some C functions in my C++ environment. And I get the following warnings because C++ doesn't allow assigning string literal to `char *` type.

> C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to char *

My Code:

```
void sys_vgui(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    //do something
    va_end(ap);
}

void open(t_buf *x)
{ 
    sys_vgui("wm deiconify .x%lx\n", x);
    sys_vgui("raise .x%lx\n", x);
    sys_vgui("focus .x%lx.text\n", x);
}
```

And I could remove these warnings by const casting the string literals as the following.

```
sys_vgui(const_cast<char *>("wm deiconify .x%lx\n"), x);
sys_vgui(const_cast<char *>("raise .x%lx\n"), x);
sys_vgui(const_cast<char *>("focus .x%lx.text\n"), x);
```

But I'm not sure if it's really safe as I've seen many people saying not to directly cast string literal to `char *`.

So I came up with the following which seems like a safer solution.

```
char str1[] = "wm deiconify .x%lx\n";
sys_vgui(str1, x);
char str2[] = "raise .x%lx\n";
sys_vgui(str2, x);
char str3[] = "focus .x%lx.text\n";
sys_vgui(str3, x);
```

But it makes my code dirty and harder to maintain as I have to create multiple variables using different names(e.g. str1, str2, str3...) whenever I use the function.

So my questions are:

1) Is it really not safe to use `const_cast<char *>` in my case?

2) Any solution to write a clean code using `char` arrays without having to create multiple variables using different names?

Comment: Why can't your function take a `const char*`?

Comment: @tkausl Becuase the `sys_vgui` function is in other header file which I include as an external library. So I want to keep the function as it is now.

Comment: It's not safe, and frankly an abuse of `const_cast`. It is intended to remove the `const` from something that was *originally* non-const. Ex: a function taking a `void fn(const Obj& obj)` argument, then caller-side performing `Obj obj; fn(obj);`. The originating object is non-const. Within `fn` one can safely mutate `obj` by using `const_cast`.  Regardless it makes for dreadfully obtuse code which must be cognitive to understand all entry paths must fulfill a contract that isn't actually enforced by anything but free will. It aches your fingers. Fine. Play by the rules anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig So would you rather recommend using char array instead? (the second option)

Comment: You could wrap `sys_vgui` in another function that takes a `const char *`, copies it into a local temporary and calls `sys_vgui` with the temp. There may be some template wizardry you can use to infer sizes and do some of the work at compile time.

Comment: @ZackLee Other than backward compatibility to compilers older than dirt, and micro architectures with horridly limited, non-standard compiler chains, there is no reason for a function claiming to never modify something to demand a non-const pointer or reference to it. After lamenting to the SDK authors, I would use arrays or some other legitimate approach. As I said, play by the rules.

Comment: Absolitely every single C library that uses sys_vgui passes string literals to it. Do what you will with this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe as long as `sys_vgui` does not modify the string, which presumably it doesn't because modifying a string literal has undefined behavior in C, `const` or not. So if you have something like

```
sys_vgui("wm deiconify .x%lx\n", x);
```

in C, then the C++ version with `const_cast` is just as safe.

However, to de-uglify the C++ code, I'd probably write a wrapper function:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void xsys_vgui(const char *fmt, Ts ...args) {
    sys_vgui(const_cast<char *>(fmt), args ...);
}
```

Now

```
xsys_vgui("wm deiconify .x%lx\n", x);
```

should "just work" in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you really know that `sys_vgui` doesn’t use the passed pointer to modify something, it’s fine in practice, although dirty, because that assumption is just in your head.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can use `std::string::data`:

```
sys_vgui(std::string{"wm deiconify .x%lx\n"}.data(), x);
```

Prior to that (in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)) you have to specify the size manually to `std::array` (including null terminator, but the compiler will probably complain anyway if it’s wrong)

```
sys_vgui(std::array<char, 20>{"wm deiconify .x%lx\n"}.data(), x);
```

Comment: But I have to use `C++11` or `C++14` unfortunately.

Comment: @ZackLee i added another approach

Comment: This is not an assumption in one's head. It is easily verifiable by looking at the source. Even before that, it's easy to see that the argument is a printf style format string. You can assume that the library intends to modify it, but this means you totally distrust the library and suspect it's evil. Why use it at all then? A little bit of common sense doesn't hurt!

Comment: @n.m. You try to not forego any checks the compiler offers you. There are a lot of bugs that come from false assumptions. The compiler is your friend, don’t avoid it! OP asked for »Any solution to write a clean code […] without having to create multiple variables using different names«, i presented a safe one (from a language POV), although without `char[]` – we are in [tag:C++] after all.

Comment: @Darklighter This function is written in C (poorly). It is not created with C++ in mind. C and C++ are different languages. Checks that a C++ compiler offers may or may not be useful for checking C functions.

Comment: @n.m. I’m not sure how that’s relevant given the OP uses [tag:C++] to compile. It’s just good practice to not avoid const correctness checks. For the benefit of preventing the odd one out bug.

Comment: @Darklighter The function is written in C and with C in mind. Calling in from C++ code is possible because C++ can call functions written in other languages. But you cannot expect it to be a smooth painless process. You need to make some adaptations. It is up to you what adaptations you ultimately choose. `const_cast` is a safe adaptation **in this case**, because there's an overwhelming evidence for it **outside of the world of C++**, but you may prefer to ignore the evidence and rely on the C++ compiler alone, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't abuse the `const_cast` intentions (and even if not abusing it, try and contrive a way to avoid it in the first place).

This is rather hideous, but *may* do what you intend: a template version of the API you desire, designed to manufacture the requisite mutable array and forward it appropriately thereafter. For callers actually supplying non-const arrays or pointers, it should just invoke the api directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void do_function(char *ptr)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

template<size_t N>
void do_function(const char (&ar)[N])
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    char inside[N];
    std::copy(ar, ar+N, inside);
    do_function(inside+0);
}

int main()
{
    char msg[] = "array test";
    do_function(msg);

    do_function("Something const");
    do_function("Nothing");
}
```

**Output**

```
void do_function(char *)
void do_function(const char (&)[N]) [N = 16]
void do_function(char *)
void do_function(const char (&)[N]) [N = 8]
void do_function(char *)
```

Note: I've not really put this through the wringer, but it will *likely* achieve what you desire. This biggest bonus is you need not change *any* of the prior calls (beyond removing those `const_cast` misnomers). the original calls passing string literals will simply start working. All you need to is hang the template version and let the compiler sort out the rest.

Comment: That's where I was headed, but I can't figure out how to pass the varargs through. Any Variadic template tricks you can think of?

Comment: https://howcanisaythat.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/through-the-wringer-or-through-the-ringer/

Comment: @user4581301 if the first argument is always a string, yes, fairly easily. If variant args *may* be strings throughout the argument list, all demanding this montage, it gets complex quickly, but it is likely possible.

Comment: @Darklighter **Thank you**. I'm keeping that link even after I change my post =P

Comment: no need to use C arrays (and `&inside[0]` instead of `inside+0`) though, just use `std::array` and its `data` member function.

Comment: Poor C language users, they have no idea about any of this stuff and in their blissful ignorance just pass string literals to that function. What a dark future awaits them!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change `sys_vgui` then you can make a wrapper:

```
template<typename... Args>
void sys_vgui_c(char const *fmt, Args&&... args)
{
     sys_vgui( const_cast<char *>(fmt), args... );
}
```

and then call it with the string literal: `sys_vgui_c("wm deiconify .x%lx\n", x);`

Answer (score 1):

How about a variadic macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

#define my_vgui(fmt_,...) \
    do { \
        char myfmt[strlen(fmt_) + 1]; \
        strcpy(myfmt,fmt_); \
        sys_vgui(myfmt,##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)

void
sys_vgui(char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    fmt[0] |= 0;
    vprintf(fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int
main(void)
{

    my_vgui("hello\n");
    my_vgui("hello %s\n","world");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that there may be cleaner ways to do the macro, so see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: Isn't `,##` a GNU extension?

Comment: @melpomene Probably. That's why I included the link so OP can use the cleaner ways (e.g. `__VA_OPTS__` that I'm less familar with).

Comment: Well, the cleaner way is to use a real function, not a macro.

Comment: @melpomene AFAICT, to do this _without_ a cast that breaks constness (which many have stated is not so great), one needs to do something like what the macro does. And it has to be a macro because OP doesn't have a `vprintf` equivalent of `sys_vgui` (e.g. `void sys_vguivar(char *fmt,va_list ap)`) that a wrapper _function_ would need to call

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the VLA part of your code. That's not even valid in C++. And you don't need a macro; see e.g. my answer.

Comment: @melpomene I don't normally prefer VLAs myself (even in C), but I compiled it with `c++` with `-Wall` and the code compiles clean with or without `-std=c++17` [and runs]. So, I'm confused. M.M posted a similar answer to yours [interesting!], but both use `const_cast`, so I'm not sure how they get around WhozCraig's answer/comment about _abuse_ of `const_cast`. In a function, the VLA could be replaced with an overly large fixed size array (e.g. 10000) and `strncpy`, but that's a [slight] hack, too. Still, a VLA replacement would be possible (e.g. an expensive `malloc/free` or `new/delete`).

Comment: Never use `strncpy`. It is an abomination. You need `-pedantic` to get all diagnostics required by the standard.

Comment: @melpomene `x.cpp` [I presume you were thinking it compiled as C code despite using `c++`. But, before posting, I tested with a straight `sys_vgui` call and got an _"ISO C++ forbids ..."_ diagnostic]. Thus, it was compiling in C++ and it accepted the VLA, so ...? And [of course] I know how to terminate the target string after `strncpy` [which, in practice, I never use either].

Comment: Terminating the target string is only half of the problem. The other issue is that `strncpy` always writes the full `n` bytes, even if the input string is shorter. Also, you need `-pedantic`.

Comment: @melpomene `char dst[10000]; strncpy(dst,src,10000); dst[9999] = 0;` And `strncpy` will only copy up to min(10000,strlen(src)) and add the EOS if there's space in destination after copying `src` in (this is stated in the manpage and its code sample) But, what about the VLA?

Comment: @CraigEstey Its a little more complicated than that, and probably the most ill-comprehended fact about `strncpy`. It *always* writes `size` chars, where `size` is the third argument. it doesn't matter how short the source buffer is. If it is exactly `size` length, no terminator is written (which you pointed out), But if it is *shorter* it doesn't just drop a single EOS. It *tail fills* the target buffer with however many null chars are required to reach a total of `size`. In short, `strncpy` *always* writes `size` characters.

Answer (score 0):

So I've just recently started working with some embedded devices that don't fully support the C++ STL library and have had to rely on using some libraries which may or may not be attempting to be compliant with the old C standards where I believe did not have the keyword `const` defined and so functions accepting string literals would have to deal with `char*` and I think you were just supposed to "trust" that the method wouldn't write to your "string".

I'm also not fond of seeing `const_cast<char*>("abc")` anywhere I would otherwise just write `"abc"` so for my purposes, it was easy enough to define a simple macro:

`#define S_(x) const_cast<char*>(x)`

and use it as follows:

`print(S_("abc"));`

It's much more concise, assuming your namespace doesn't already have lots of single capital letter macros such as the one I chose to use.